# Sample size for each trial vs Number of trials conducted for Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: matlab, monte-carlo

I am running some Monte Carlo Simulations on Matlab. I am wondering if running more Monte Carlo Simulation trials and taking the average value of these trials is the same as running a single trial with the same total number of samples? E.g. Running 10 trials with 10,000 samples in each trial and taking the mean of the 10 trials vs Running 1 trial with 100,000 samples. Are the two procedures in fact equivalent because the computational time required would presumably be the same?

Comment: What are you simulating?

Comment: If the samples are independent, you should have the same results.

Comment: @fm361 I see... Thanks